# What tests should I run before my laptop's service warranty expires?

Tags: linux, laptop, diagnostic, maintenance

I just got an email warning me that my laptop's hardware service warranty will expire very soon. What tests should I run to identify components that are at risk of failing?

I am running Fedora Linux and can boot diagnostic software from USB if needed. My laptop is a Dell XPS 13.

Comment: the one test i know to run is to do a SMART drive monitor.

Comment: [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm)?

Comment: The same tests you run every day up to this point: asking yourself "if this thing (or my house) were to burst into flames, what would I lose and want to keep?" If you've not had any problems so far then there is no reason to expect them to happen suddenly after warranty expiration.

Comment: Warranty will not cover parts "at risk of failing" Dell usually has built in hardware tests that can be run from the bios or while in Windows....https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/xps-13-9350-laptop/diagnose

Comment: @Moab i don't expect them to replace "at risk" components, i just want to know what i'm dealing with.